# How do I create a simulated API call in rxjs that throws an error after 1 second?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Play with the code here => https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-rxjs-f8xjsh

Hi,
I'm trying to simulate a failed API Call that will emit the error value at the subscribe() { Error: } part.

```
import { from, of, pipe, forkJoin, interval, AsyncSubject, BehaviorSubject,defer, Subject, timer, observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, map, mergeMap, zipWith, delay, tap, concatAll, concat, concatWith, switchMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const apiCall = (callNumber, isError=false) => of('Api Call Result ' + callNumber).pipe(
  tap(_=>console.log('Calling Api ' + callNumber)),
  delay(1000),
  tap(_=> throwError(() => new Error('ERROR')))
);

apiCall(99,true).subscribe({
  next: x=>console.log(x),
  error: e=>console.log(e)
});
```

Currently the error is not caught i.e. logged.
Can someone help?

Stackblitz =>  https://stackblitz.com/edit/playground-rxjs-f8xjsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working example, inspired by [@JSmart523](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7158380/jsmart523)

```typescript
const apiCall = (callNumber: number, isError = false) =>
  of('Api Call Result ' + callNumber).pipe(
    tap((_) => console.log('some log before')),
    delay(1000),
    switchMap((_) => {
      if (isError) {
        throw new Error(`ERROR`);
      } else {
        return of(_);
      }
    })
  );

apiCall(99, true).subscribe({
  next: (x) => console.log(x),
  error: (e: Error) => console.log(e.message),
});
```

Comment: Thank you I have updated my stackblitz and will keep it for future reference

Answer (score 2):

`tap` executes the function and then emits whatever it received, unchanged.

`throwError` is a function that returns an observable.

So, `someObservable.pipe(x)` will return an observable that emits an error if `x` is

- `map(() => { throw new Error('msg') })`, or
- `switchMap(() => throwError('msg'))`

... or you can simply create a new observable with `throwError('msg'))` and there's no need to pipe anything...

but `tap(() =>` *anything*`)` won't change what the observable emits.